# Embed Segue with Custom Class

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, segue, container-view

Hi i'm pretty new to IOS app development and I have somewhat of a problem. I created a view controller and I have a table view controller embed as a segue inside a container on the view controller.

By default the table view controller shows when I test the app. However when I add a custom class for the table view controller it does not show in the container.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out. Had to comment out the methods in the tableview sub class for data source.

Answer (score 0):

just follow this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1 and http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

and try to post some screenshots or code for better understation of you question